# How do you do a highlighter marker effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am very new to Photoshop and I am having trouble figuring something out.

I would like to have an effect that looks exactly like a real highlighter. But I want it to really act like a highlighter too, i.e. I would like to brush over my pencil tool marks with this highlighter so that I can still see the pencil underneath it.

So far I have tried lowering the Opacity on the brush tool but that doesn't create that bright highlighter effect I'm looking for.

If anybody knows how to do this that would be awesome!

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't forget to make your "brush" a stubby rectangle that's the same shape as the felt tip on a highlighter. (You already knew that.) Welcome to graphic design stack exchange.

Comment: @Stan Thanks Stan, I'll do that! And I think I realize now that I can just paint a bright color on the background behind the layer with the pencil and it looks just the way I want it to look! (I haven't really worked with layers before so I didn't realize it would look the way it looks if I did this...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your markings into a new top layer, give to it blending mode Multiply

An example:

[image]